# how to get plugin help in maven?

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I don't have plugin help in the directory %HOME%.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins. but my maven Setup ha no problem. I don't know why I don't have that plugin and how should I get it?
This is the output of mvn --version in the cmd:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.3
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version: 1.6.0_13
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows Vista",version:"6.8"
```

when I write mvn help:effective pom.xml the rezult has error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Total time: 25.44s
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/254M
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current project
```

It is the code in the file pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> <groupId>com.companyname.project-group</groupId> CHAPTER 3
TUTORIALS POINT
Simply Easy Learning Page 8
<artifactId&gtproject</artifactId> <version>1.0</version> </project>
```

This is the rezult of mvn -X help:effective-pom

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
```

Comment: Just simply try `mvn help:help` that will download the maven-help-plugin..

Comment: but there is error when i try mvn help:help! seems it can't download but I don't know why?1

Comment: provide your pom.xml here. it would be hard to guess what is your problem without code.

Comment: and this will help you to insert readable XML: [escape xml online](http://google.com/?q=escape+xml+online)

Answer (score 0):

goto your project and invoke

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

that will force download this plugin

Comment: when I invoke mvn help:effective-pom there is error in downloading:

Comment: post the log of `mvn help:effective-pom -e`

Comment: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] NO plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current projects and in groups.

Comment: can you post the entire stacktrace in question

Comment: I can't post image becuase of my reputation, and stacktrace is so long but I will try to write much of it in the question @Jigar Joshi

Comment: useful information is enough (first 10 lines of each stack would do)

Comment: I edited to question, now there is the stacktrace @Jigar Joshi